# Middleware auth перенаправляет api роуты на /home

Tags: php, laravel, api, роутинг

Файл `routes/api.php`:

```
Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', 
    function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::middleware('auth:api')->group(function() 
{
   Route::get('/tasks','TaskController@index');
});
```

После попытки зайти на `/api/tasks` перенаправляет на `/home`, как сделать так чтобы после проверки возвращало обратно?

При изменении `Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` c /home на /api/tasks возникает бесконечный цикл проверок.

Если прописать роуты в `web.php` то все нормально.

Laravel 5.5

---

Решил с помощью `laravel/passport`

Статья на медиуме:
https://medium.com/techcompose/create-rest-api-in-laravel-with-authentication-using-passport-133a1678a876

Comment: а почему `/api/tasks`? Вы же не задали префикс `api`. Кроме того, сюда попадают запросы с header `Content-Type: application/json`, а не запросы просто по url. Иначе в чём бы была разница между api.php и web.php

Comment: @n.osennij  - https://prnt.sc/mhbkxg - все объявляется без проблем. А вот про json это интересно, сча кое что попробую

Comment: @n.osennij, https://prnt.sc/mhboyp - попробовал через Postman